# AttributeError: DescribeData: Method shapeFieldName does not exist

Tags: visual-studio, gis, arcpy

skipFlds = [desc.shapeFieldName, desc.OIDFieldName]
Error: AtrributeError: DescribeData: Method shapeFieldName does not exist

Answer (score 0):

That error is common when a shape/geometry field doesn't exist, like in a regular table.  Double check you are describing a spatial dataset; if so, then the dataset may be corrupted and ArcPy isn't recognizing a spatial data type exists.

```
>>> import arcpy
>>> 
>>> fc =   # path to feature class
>>> tbl =  # path to table
>>> 
>>> desc_fc = arcpy.Describe(fc)
>>> desc_fc.shapeFieldName
'Shape'
>>> 
>>> desc_tbl = arcpy.Describe(tbl)
>>> desc_tbl.shapeFieldName
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: DescribeData: Method shapeFieldName does not exist
>>>
```